# How should multiple value thrift of Java enumeration class be defined?

Tags: java, thrift

```
# java
public class B extends Enum implements TEnum {
    B a = new B("a", 1, 1);
    B b = new B("b", 2, 5);

    int val;

    public B(String s, int i, int val) {
        super(s, i);
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

How should I define the above structure in thrift?

Comment: In Java, I do not know thrift, you are not supposed to extend `Enum` (assuming Java's standard class), but you declare an enumeration class: `public enum B  { A, B }` or even `public enum B implements TEnum { A(1), B(5); ... }` - see the corresponding official tutorial [Enum Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) or Java Language Specification [8.9. Enum Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9)

Comment: In thrift framework, enum definition is an integer value, but I need to define multiple integer values of an enum type. For example in the java structure
```java
#java
public enum A implement TEnum {
   a(1,1),
   b(2,3);
   int ord;
   int val;
   public A(int ord, int val) {
     this.ord=ord;
     this.val=val;
   }
}
````
Sorry, my English is not good

Answer (score 0):

In Thrift an enum is simply an integer. It's not possible to have more complex structures on top of it.

```
 enum Foo {
      Bar = 0
      Baz = 1
      AnswerToEverythingEtc = 42     
 }
```

Remember that Thrift is compatible to 20+ target languages and dialects and most environments do not have the capability to do such stuff like having two values on an enum. To model that with Thrift consider using a struct

```
 struct TwoValues {
      1: i32 ord
      2: i32 val
 }
```